# SQL SUM problems

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sum

I have this Query:

```
Select     Denumire,Sum(Livrari.Cantitate)as Stoc,
           isnull(Sum(Facturi_Emise.Cantitate),0) as 'Sold',
           isnull(Sum(Livrari.Cantitate),0)-isnull(sum(Facturi_Emise.Cantitate),0) As 'Stoc After Sales', 
           Livrari.Id_Depozit

From       Livrari
Left join  Produse On Livrari.Id_Produs=Produse.Id_Produs
Left join  Facturi_Emise On Produse.Id_Produs=Facturi_Emise.Id_Produs

group by   Denumire, Livrari.Id_Depozit
order by   Denumire
```

I need to get the Stock, the quantity of the items that are required to be sold, and what I got in the 2 deposits after the items are sold. But in the table "Livrari" I got the same item in both deposit, with the amount of 300 for deposit 1, and 300 for deposit 2 and when I make the sum and group by Id_Depozit I get that item with the amount of 600 in deposit 1 and 600 in deposit 2, same is for table Facutri_Emise as I should take only 250 items from deposit 1 and 300 from deposit 2, it takes 550(250+300) from both deposit and I got the Stoc after Sale 50 for each, instead of 50 for deposit 1 and 0 for deposit 2.

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/811f5/1)

My problem is that the result in row 8 and 9(that means Pahare) in column Stoc should be 300 for each. In next column Sold, row 8 should be 250 and for row 9 300. In the end, in column Stoc after Sale should be the difference, as row 8=50, row 9=0.
I mean each time a products repeats, my query is gonna make the sum and put the same value in deposit 1 and in deposit 2, as I give different values for each deposit it should show me the correspondent values. A supplier will bring a certain amount if items(let's say apples) into deposit 1 and another supplier will bring another amount of apples in deposit 2. When the bill is made("Facturi_Emise") for the client I should sent an amount of apples from deposit 1 and another from deposit 2 and I wanna see what amount remains in one deposit,and what remains in other one.

Comment: just type some sample data here with the schema design.

Comment: Output-"Facturi_Emise" (Id_Factura(PK),CNP(FK),Id_Produs(FK),Cantitate(Quantity),Id_Depozit)
1/1750130120056/5/21/1
2/1870823130025/3/32/1
3/************/7/250/1
4/************/2/55/2
5/************/12/5/1
6/************/5/10/1
7/************/11/1
8/************/7/2
9/************/6/2
Input-"Livrari" (Id_Livrare(PK),Id_Furnizor(FK),Id_Produs(Fk),Cantitate(Quantity),Id_Depozit(Fk)

Comment: You're still missing a table's worth of starting data.  Could we get an actual table of desired results?  And we tend to prefer sample data be in text form for easy copying.  @Tanner - as long as there is at least one non-null value, `SUM(...)` will actually [ignore `null` values](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/36386/0), so that's not necessary.

Comment: Here's a sample SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/26d14/2. Can you edit it and replicate your data and highlight the issue. I've tried to only pick the columns that are required to keep it as simple as possible.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/MctTTRs.png

Comment: The Data from the tables http://i.imgur.com/zFaiydL.png

Comment: @Tanner the same problem occurs in your code,too. As in Sold column you should take 200 pieces of Mere only from Deposit number 1 and 0 pieces from Deposit number2. In Stoc column,row Mere should be 300 Dep1, 300 Dep2 and there are 600 in Dep2 and 200 in Dep2.

Comment: @Andrei-Paul my sample shows the same issues because it's based on your query. I merely posted the fiddle so you could update the data and explain what it should produce, then people can modify that to make their lives easier

Comment: Okey. My database looks something like this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/811f5/1

Comment: @Andrei-Paul Add that fiddle link and these comments to the question now as it is important content so it belongs in the question

Comment: @Andrei-Paul - Do you care [if some of the amounts are negative](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/811f5/8/1)?  `Id_Depozit` is in both tables, why weren't you joining on that too?  Otherwise things start getting more difficult - you need running sums and other stuff.  Try paring your sample data to only a few (like 1 or 2) items that are causing you problems.  Can we get, for the sample data you've given, a complete table of the actual results you want?  Doesn't have to be on the fiddle, just a simple text table containing everything is enough.

Comment: What I want I already wrriten in the question. I even attached some pictures of how all my tables look like.{ i.imgur.com/MctTTRs.png ; i.imgur.com/zFaiydL.png }. That's the query that I want(the result), only that I found out if I got an item which is in both deposit, the result will be the sum of the whole amount, while I need the amount for Deposit 1 and Deposit 2 separate so when a client want that item I can make the bill and say that the necessary amount was taken from Deposit 1 or 2. And on the end of the day when I wanna check the status of my amount, to see how many items I got left.

Comment: I have got one week since I started to learn SQL and I found an exercise that sounds like : Create tables for a company(Client-CLients ; Produse-Products ; Facturi emise(iesire)-Bills for clients(Output);Furnizor-Suppliers ; Livrari produse(intrari)-Supplier deliveries(Input)). Update,Modify,Alter tables,etc so you may add Personal info and more details for Clients and Suppliers, all the products that you sell, their price from supplier and the price you are selling, Stock for each product, Stock of the amount the client want to buy, Stock at the end of the day.

Comment: The items will pe put in 2 Deposits. @Clockwork-Muse that should be the exercise and what I should do. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is.
It is not ordered by deposit numbers,but it's okey.

```
SELECT Produse.Denumire, 
Isnull(a.suma,0) AS Intrari,
 Isnull(b.suma,0) AS Iesiri, 
isnull(a.suma,0) - isnull(b.suma,0) AS Stoc
FROM Produse 
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT ID_Produs, Sum(Cantitate) AS suma FROM Livrari GROUP BY ID_Produs)
 AS a 
ON Produse.ID_Produs = a.ID_Produs
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT ID_Produs, Sum(Cantitate) AS suma FROM Facturi_Emise GROUP BY ID_Produs)
 AS b
ON Produse.ID_Produs = b.ID_Produs
```

[SOLLUTION](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c6b4a/2)

Answer (score -1):

```
Select     Denumire,Sum(Livrari.Cantitate)as Stoc,
           SUM(ISNULL(Facturi_Emise.Cantitate,0)) as 'Sold',
           SUM(ISNULL(Livrari.Cantitate,0))-SUM(ISNULL(Facturi_Emise.Cantitate,0)) As 'Stoc After Sales', 
           Livrari.Id_Depozit

From       Livrari
Left join  Produse On Livrari.Id_Produs=Produse.Id_Produs
Left join  Facturi_Emise On Produse.Id_Produs=Facturi_Emise.Id_Produs
```

and Livrari.Id_Depozit=Facturi_Emise.Id_Depozit
    group by   Denumire, Livrari.Id_Depozit
    order by   Denumire

You need ceck null before sum, soo first ISNULL and then SUM.
If you SUM and one is null then all SUM will be null.